# How to make a child div position:absolute responsive in height

Tags: html, css

I found this CSS-trick to create
[CSS tabs without using JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/). I found then [here on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096310/convert-horizontal-tabs-to-vertical-html-css-only-no-js) the way on how to re-design the script to create vertical tabs and this is my "final" version:

```
<div id="contenitore">
  <div class="tabs">

    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>       
      <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
      <div class="content"><p>Content 1</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1" checked>       
      <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
      <div class="content"><p>Content 2</p></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
#contenitore {width:100%;
              height:auto;}
.tabs {width:100%;
       height:auto;
       position: relative;
       clear: both;
       margin: 1% 0;}
.tab {width:100%;
      height: auto;}
.tab label {padding: 1%; 
            margin: 0; 
            position: relative;
            left: 0;        
            width:6.5%;
            height:auto;
            display: block;}
.tab [type=radio] {display: none;}
.content {width:87.5%;
          height:auto;
          position: absolute;
          top:0;
          bottom:0;
          left:8.5%; /*= width tab label (6.5%) + padding (1% = 1%left+!%right)*/
          right: 0;
          padding: 2%;}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {background: white;
                              z-index: 2;}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {z-index: 1;}
```

I didn't understand why the div .content is not responsive at all even if I set height:auto (with 100% is not responsive as well).
Is it due to the particular html structure and the connection with other elements like inputs and labels or I'm making some mistakes?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "responsive"? What is the behaviour you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @FrancescoLorenzetti84
I mean that the div content doesn't expand itself in height depending on what is inside it and I can't understand why; it's simply fixed in height. I should integrate this layout with a php script that extract images from a database and the div must be of course flexible. Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
bottom: 0;
```

From the .content selector. If you set it like that on position absolute the bottom rim will touch the bottom of its container.